# Reverse command that moved everything to /usr/lib/somewhere

Tags: command-line, 18.10

I have written this command:

```
sudo mv /* /usr/lib/I'm not sure about this folder name/
```

to install flash player, and many files were copied to this directory `/usr/lib/I'm not sure about this folder name/` and my Ubuntu doesn't work now.

I'm able to use live Ubuntu. Can I use some reverse command to repair my Ubuntu? If yes, what is the reverse command?

`fstab` content:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=1d24ddd9-b5ed-45f7-9770-9a599cecf4a3 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: There are no direct revers comment. From live media you will have to mount your old / (root) dirirectory, and then move the relevant directories from /usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/ to / . What are the output of `ls -la /usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/`

Answer (score 2):

The reverse would be

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/* /
```

but that is from your actual system.

From a live session you need to mount the partition. After mounting the disk `cd` to it using command line and then issue is from THAT directory. That would make it:

```
cd /media/{device}/
sudo mv usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/* .
```

In between you can check with `ls usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/` if you are in the correct directory.

All commands here should be executed after verifying they are correct and valid. So use a lot of `ls` commands to see what the results are. After the `cd` for instance `ls usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/` should list your file system files that belong in `/`.

Good luck with this :) Anyone can make a mistake but the experts then make sure there is no mistake in repairing the problem.

---

From Soren A:

> if you move everything from /usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/ to / you will get the old content of /usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/ moved to / too. It is better to move the few relevant directories one by one.

My method works but you will also move the files that should be in `/usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/` so it makes a bit of a mess of `/`. To clean that up you need to remove these files or do a little bit extra to start with:

So the new approach would be ...

```
cd /media/{device}/
ls usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/
```

Investigate the results. Anything that looks like it belongs in the root of the device can then be mv'd to `/media/{device}/`. Some observations: the files in / will all belong to user "root" and group "root" and  will all be directories (1st char of the result of ls will be a `d`) or symlinks (`l`)

Comment: If you move everything from /usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/ to / you will get the old content of /usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/ moved to / too. It is better to move the few relevant directories one by one.

Comment: @SorenA good call :X

Comment: Valid point, but I'd give rescuing the OS priority over salvaging the Pepper Flash plugin any time.

Comment: Thank you. Any solution for my fstab file?

Answer (score 0):

Once you are in the live system mount the disk where Ubuntu were installed and perform a command to move back in place all files you have move.

For example, on the live system suppose the computer disk are automatically mounted on /media/disk-name enter in it with a terminal:

```
cd /media/disk-name
```

from that path execute the following command which **should** put every thing in place

```
mv ./usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/* ./
```

**NOTE: the `./` is not an error it is important to determinate that is the current path you are working**

to be more safe use the absolute path:

```
mv /media/disk-name/usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/* /media/disk-name/
```

**An annotation:** when you use wildcard character and recursive command it is recommended to think twice before run the command, for example if you execute a `rm -rf ./` and you are in the root directory, you delete your entire system, moving is also dangerous! Prefer to use always the full path and a filter with the wildcard character, this to avoid distraction error could be potentially destructive.

Comment: I did. now ubuntu waiting in booting page(page with ubuntu logoo and 5 dot changing color from red to white) for half an hour.

Comment: ok, may all answer you (me included) we do not think the boot directory are a mount point, please run again in to live system and add in the question fstab content, the path after mounting should be /media/disk-name/etc/fstab

Comment: Also I read other solution I use ```busybox ls``` and press ctrl+D after that on live system, but it doesn't work.(that was before I post the fstab content)